# copy specific columns from notepad++ to excel sheet

Tags: regex, macros, notepad++

Can I use macros in notepad++ to select specific columns and paste these columns into specific cells in excel sheet automatically. If possible how?
Please help on this or any other suggestions may help in routine tasks with a lot of copy and pasted to be run automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Added info on automation tools.**

You don't need macros. Notepad++ has column mode which allows you to select text columns and copy it on clipboard which you then can paste in Excel. See here for a little video about how to do this: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

If you want to automate this process then you need automation tool that will record your keystrokes/mouse and other activities and replay whenever you need it. Below are some of the tools that does that and may fit your need:

1. [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)
2. [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)
3. [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Comment: @user2792748 You just hold Alt while clicking and dragging the mouse to select the area you want.

Comment: I know this column mode but I do this every day. I copy for example column 1 and paste it on excel sheet cell A1 , then column 2 and paste it in B1 in excel,... if possible I want a method or script to do this automatically to copy these columns and paste them in the excel sheet in one step

Comment: I see, what you need is actually automation tool that will record your activity and repeat it at anytime you want. I've updated the answer with some of the popular tools.